# How to stop the 'gem' utility from accessing my home directory?

Tags: windows, ruby, unicode, rubygems

When I run

```
gem install <somegem>
```

command the `gem` utility tries to access my home directory. It contains some non-latin characters and installation fails because of that. For example:

```
E:\ruby\bin>gem install <somegem>
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory - C:\Documents and Settings\<user>
```

If I switch to another user account with a username containing ASCII characters only `gem` works fine.

Does anybody know how to tell gem NOT to check my home directory?

**UPDATE**: I tried to set up GEM_HOME as suggested below but it didn't help (still checks the user home directory)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just change HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH before running *gem*, and restore after (if needed).

I've changed my *gem.bat* like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET _HOMEDRIVE=%HOMEDRIVE%
SET _HOMEPATH=%HOMEPATH%
SET HOMEDRIVE=E:
SET HOMEPATH=/Dev/Ruby
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "E:/Dev/Ruby/bin/gem" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
SET HOMEDRIVE=%_HOMEDRIVE%
SET HOMEPATH=%_HOMEPATH%
```

*E:/Dev/Ruby/* is my Ruby path. It seems that HOMEPATH can be changed to anything else with ASCII only characters in path.

Comment: Another, better way is to set HOME environment variable in “gem” script itself. Add following line to the beginning of “bin/gem”:

ENV['HOME'] = "E:/Dev/Ruby"

This fix works for all “gem” usages. As previously mentioned, this path can be changed, using ruby dir isn't required.

Comment: Those script changes worked a treat with my Windows7. Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm. They really should fix this though

Comment: Same problem ant setting HOME in gem script file is the only solution which works. Tahnks.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler to write:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET HOMEPATH=
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
ECHO.This version of Ruby has not been built with support for Windows 95/98/Me.
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

In this case you don't need to write your path and can replace or redistribute with file for new installations

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try changing the value of the GEM_HOME environment directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you GEM_PATH is set to your user directory, it will still access it. Try changing GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

just run postinstall file pi.bat or pi.sh
this file is in ./RubyDevKit/postinstall.

this worked for me. it seems that installer of cygwin broke my settings.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the command prompt console as something might have jacked it up. I had the same issue, and restarting the console reset my environment.

Comment: revised with explanation.