# OSX El Capitan, gem install "ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL) Invalid argument"

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods, bundler, osx-elcapitan, gem-bundler

gem install fails for any gem (e.g. bundler, cocoapods).

`$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
    Invalid argument`

## Background

On a new macbook (Mid 2015) running OSX El Capitan v10.11.6 (15G31), I started setting it up for development work and installed xcode8, brew & ruby. My `gem env`:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/__username__/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/__username__/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /Users/__username__/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "-n/usr/local/bin"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
```

## Some of existing posts:

Many of the existing posts are focused on another similar error you get that is related to "rootless" security feature in El Capitan:

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted`

Some of Errno::EPERM related posts: [1: CocoaPods issue 3680](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3680), [2: Stackoverflow Windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987300/error-running-gem-install-on-windows-7-64-bit), 
[3: Bundler issue 4065](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4065)

## What didn't work:

### `gem install` variants

`$ sudo gem install bundler -n /usr/local/bin -V`

### Setting $GEM_HOME to /usr/local/bin and ~/.gems.

`echo $GEM_HOME
/usr/local/bin
echo $GEM_HOME
~/.gems`

### "rootless" disable

`sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0"; sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0):

Seems rubygems version 2.5.1 has some issues. I installed older ruby version 2.2.5 that comes with rubygems version 2.4.5.1.

Used `brew install ruby`, `brew uninstall ruby` to fix the issue (Errno::EINVAL).

`gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.5 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 319) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ashok.meena/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/__username__/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/__username__/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/__username__/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/__username__/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/__username__/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - /Users/__username__/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "-n/usr/local/bin"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/__username__/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/libexec`